# Audio through Bluetooth headset only work with calls

Tags: headset

I have paired the Klip Xtreme UltraVox Bluetooth headset to my BLU phone. When I made a call, the audio is working fine. But if I use YouTube or a video on the phone, it comes through the speaker.

How to route the audio through the Bluetooth headset?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the **Settings** app on your phone and choose **Bluetooth**. You'll see a list of paired devices. (Alternatively, from the quick settings panel, tap the **Bluetooth** label, not the icon, and then click **More settings**. They both get you to the same screen.)

From that screen, find your headset in the list of paired devices, and click the gear icon next to it. A dialog comes up where you can edit the name of the headset, and below that it says **Use for**. In that list, turn on **Media audio**, and click OK.

Comment: I don't have  Media audio option